# Doctrine 2.1 - entity inserting

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have question about inserting entity into a database. I have two models:

```
class News {
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="news")
     * @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    protected $author;

}

class User {
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="author")
     */
    protected $news;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->news = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    }

}
```

To add new news I must include both `User` and `News` classes (if they're in separate files, for ex. UserModel.php and NewsModel.php) and write a code:

```
$news = new News()
$news->setTitle('TEST title');
$news->setAuthor($database->find('User', 1));
$database->persist($news);
```

My question is: Is there any way to insert news without including `User` class?

Comment: Do you mean: How to make a news without user in the sense that a news must not have a user?

Comment: I meant, that I could give only an ID of User instead of whole User object. For ex. sth like `$news->setAuthor(1);` or `INSERT INTO News VALUES ('TEST title', 1);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to actually load the User.

Instead, you can use a [reference proxy](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#reference-proxies):

```
<?PHP
$news = new News()
$news->setTitle('TEST title');
$news->setAuthor($em->getReference('User',1));
$em->persist($news);
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question to You. Is there any way to do this Reference, but with other column (not ID)?

Comment: I don't believe so.  You need the identity value of the referenced entity.

Comment: Have another question. Is this `getReference()` is faster than `find()` method?

Answer (score 1):

one other thing you could do (thinking in a more object-oriented kinda way) is add a method called `addNews($news)` on your user entity:

```
public function addNews($news) {
    // you should check if the news doesn't already exist here first
    $this->news->add($news);
    $news->setAuthor($this);
}
```

and add cascade persist to your mapping:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="author", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $news;
```

then fetch your user, add the news, and merge the changes:

```
$news = new News()
$news->setTitle('TEST title');    
$author = $database->find('User', 1);

$author->addNews($news);

//merge changes on author entity directly
$em->merge($author);
```

I preferr this approach because it gives you the opportunity to do extra checks or controls while adding the news, making for reusable and easy to read code